# C makefile not compiling after change in makefile

Tags: mysql, c, makefile

I have a makefile that I want to be able to execute after updating it.

```
EXE = sensor log
LDIR = lib
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(DEFINES)
LFLAGS = -Wall -L./$(LDIR) -Wl,-rpath=./$(LDIR)
CDFLAGS = -Wall -c -fPIC
LDFLAGS = -Wall -shared

DEFINES = -D SET_ID=20

.SUFFIXES:

all: sensor log
debug: DEFINES += -DDEBUG
debug: all

$(EXE) : % : %.o $(LDIR)/liblist.so $(LDIR)/libtcpsocket.so
    @echo "\n***** LINKING $< *****"
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $< -llist -ltcpsocket -lpthread -lm -o $@

liblist libmyqueue libtcpsocket libsensor_db : % : $(LDIR)/%.so

%.o : %.c %.check
    @echo "\n***** COMPILING $< *****"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o$@ $<

$(LDIR)/lib%.so : %.c %.check
    $(eval name = $(basename $<))
    @echo "\n***** COMPILING LIB $< *****"
    $(CC) $(CDFLAGS) $<
    mkdir -p $(LDIR)
    @echo "\n***** LINKING LIB $< *****"
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(name).o -o $(LDIR)/lib$(name).so

.PHONY : clean clean-all *.check

%.check : %.c
    @echo "\n***** CPPCHECK $< *****"
    cppcheck --enable=all $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(EXE) *~

clean-all: clean
    rm -rf $(LDIR)
```

The issue is that I want to be able to compile with a parameter `DEBUG` or not (just an example). However, since the files haven't been changed itself between last compilation, make just tells me there is nothing to be done. How can I solve this?

Also, when compiling in the command line for a mysql file, I normally use `$(mysql_config --cflags --libs)` to compile it. However, doing this in the makefile causes it to turn green. How do I do this?

Comment: This is unclear. Do you want Make to rebuild the objects when the makefile has been modified, or when you are executing it with a parameter (e.g. `make DEBUG=true`) that you didn't use last time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `DEBUG` parameter, to easiest way is to add a parameter in the command line. You can do this by adding the next lines before the first target:

```
ifeq ($(DEBUG),1)
DEFINES += -DDEBUG
endif
```

And even this, to restrict the `DEBUG` parameter to the command line only:

```
ifeq ("$(origin DEBUG)", "command line")
ifeq ($(DEBUG),1)
DEFINES += -DDEBUG
endif
endif
```

And then you just have to do this to compile in debug mode:

```
$ make DEBUG=1
```

For the mysql thing, just use the `shell` command like that:

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -c $(DEFINES) $(shell mysql_config --cflags --libs)
```

Comment: This will not help, the issue is if you do a `make` followed by a `make DEBUG=1` , the source code will not be re-built with the latter command - and "fixing" that is non-trivial.